# Where is Auto Layout box in Xcode 4.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to compile for a binary but am getting an error on 4 files stating:
Interface Builder was unable to determine the type of “FileName.xib".
I got some feedback saying I should disable the Use Auto Layout feature, but can't find it. I've attached a screen shot of what my editor looks like, where I should be seeing the option (I've narrowed the image to be more portable).

Is this a version issue? At the moment I'm stuck with Xcode 4.0.1.

Thanks for any and all help.

Cayce

[image: Xcode Editor Window]

Answer (score 1):

Autolayout isn't supported in 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Use latest version of Xcode then you can see

[image: Autolayout box]